# How to compile PHP 7.1 with ZTS

Tags: php, pthreads, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.1, zts

I see on the github PThread project page that php7+ is supported.

I have php7.1.6 on an ubuntu distribution (16.04)

I can't find any PPA that offer php7.1-zts.

How can i enable zts on php7.1 to install pthreads ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my setup script

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /etc/php7
mkdir -p /etc/php7/cli

git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git -b PHP-7.0.17 --depth=1
cd php-src/ext
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads -b master pthreads

cd ..

./buildconf --force

./configure --prefix=/etc/php7 --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --disable-cgi \
   --enable-soap --enable-intl --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-readline --with-curl \
   --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
   --enable-sockets --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --with-enchant --with-gettext \
   --with-gd --enable-exif --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xsl \
   --enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-calendar --enable-simplexml --enable-json \
   --enable-hash --enable-session --enable-xml --enable-wddx --enable-opcache \
   --with-pcre-regex --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \
   --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/etc --enable-cli --enable-maintainer-zts \
   --with-tsrm-pthreads --enable-debug --enable-fpm \
   --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data

make && make install

chmod o+x /etc/php7/bin/phpize
chmod o+x /etc/php7/bin/php-config

cd ext/pthreads*
/etc/php7/bin/phpize

./configure --prefix=/etc/php7 --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-pthreads=shared --with-php-config=/etc/php7/bin/php-config

make && make install

cd ../../
cp -r php.ini-development /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

cp php.ini-development /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini
echo "extension=pthreads.so" > /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini
echo "zend_extension=opcache.so" >> /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

ln --symbolic /etc/php7/bin/php /usr/bin/php

export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0
```

Also you can use my docker-container `docker pull buildok/zts`

Comment: Thanks, it's seem to work fine as is. i will test with php 7.1 branch. Do you now if it's possible to have a php apache module when compiling from sources ?

Comment: @Khorwin I use nginx usually. If you need to apache-mod support, you can add a parameter in ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
look detail about this http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: @Khorwin Pthreads cannot be used in a web server environment, so you will not be able to have pthreads enabled if PHP is loaded as an Apache module.

Comment: @buildok You have debug mode enabled - that probably isn't desirable for most people here. Also, the TSRM defaults to POSIX threads, so there's no real need to specify it.

Comment: Maybe you are right, anyway I advise to use ./configure --help 
to find out about these parameters before compile

Comment: I have some problems with 7.1 today.. so the solutions was use this version of pthreads: https://github.com/neomacedo/pthreads/releases/tag/v3.1.7-beta.1

Appear to be the master only compatible with 7.2+ now

Comment: Hi.  This is great in that it is a functional answer...but one question, why are you installing binaries under /etc?  That's very unusual; binaries generally go under some path like /usr/local/bin...

Comment: Not working, I get error:" ‘zend_op_array {aka struct _zend_op_array}’ has no member na
med ‘run_time_cache’; did you mean ‘run_time_cache__ptr’?" at 2nd command "make && make install"

Comment: @JeremLachkar https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/944

Comment: I finally used new PHP 7.4 librairy "Parallel". Don't forget to git checkout PHP-7.4, to compile PHP from source (it was a nightmare to compile using master branch)

Answer (score 1):

**On Ubuntu server**

I changed the version to 7.4.16

`git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git -b PHP-7.0.17 --depth=1`

I had to install a few dependencies, before being able to recompile PHP.

The packages needed were:

`apt install bison re2c zlib1g-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libenchant-dev libonig-dev libpspell-dev libedit-dev libreadline-dev libxslt-dev`

Also
WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-zip, --with-mcrypt, --with-gd, --with-jpeg-dir, --with-png-dir, --with-freetype-dir, --enable-hash, --enable-wddx, --with-pcre-regex

So with php 7.4 you probably want to do:
`./configure --prefix=/etc/php7 --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --disable-cgi \ --enable-soap --enable-intl with-openssl --with-readline --with-curl \ --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \ --enable-sockets --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --with-enchant --with-gettext \ --enable-exif --with-xsl \ --enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-calendar --enable-simplexml --enable-json \ --enable-session --enable-xml --enable-opcache \ --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \ --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/etc --enable-cli --enable-maintainer-zts \ --with-tsrm-pthreads --enable-debug --enable-fpm \ --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data`

After you will find that php7.4 is not compatible with pthreads
and you will find this error, where the maintainer has stopped development of pthreads and moved to parallel.
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/929