# Enable Thread Safety for php 7.1

Tags: php, multithreading, compilation, pthreads

I clone php 7.1:

```
apshenichnikov@IAS-WS-UX02:~/php-src$ git status
On branch PHP-7.1
```

I make ./buildconf --force
I run:

```
./configure \
  --enable-hash \
  --prefix=/usr/local/php \
  --enable-maintainer-zts \
  --with-tsrm-pthreads \
  --with-pdo-oci=shared,instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient,12.1
```

I successfully run make & make install:

```
apshenichnikov@IAS-WS-UX02:~/php-src$ sudo make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/
Installing PHP CLI binary:        /usr/local/php/bin/
Installing PHP CLI man page:      /usr/local/php/php/man/man1/
Installing phpdbg binary:         /usr/local/php/bin/
Installing phpdbg man page:       /usr/local/php/php/man/man1/
Installing PHP CGI binary:        /usr/local/php/bin/
Installing PHP CGI man page:      /usr/local/php/php/man/man1/
Installing build environment:     /usr/local/php/lib/php/build/
Installing header files:           /usr/local/php/include/php/
Installing helper programs:       /usr/local/php/bin/
  program: phpize
  program: php-config
Installing man pages:             /usr/local/php/php/man/man1/
  page: phpize.1
  page: php-config.1
Installing PEAR environment:      /usr/local/php/lib/php/
[PEAR] Archive_Tar    - already installed: 1.4.0
[PEAR] Console_Getopt - already installed: 1.4.1
[PEAR] Structures_Graph- already installed: 1.1.1
[PEAR] XML_Util       - already installed: 1.3.0
[PEAR] PEAR           - already installed: 1.10.1
Warning! a PEAR user config file already exists from a previous PEAR installation at '/home/apshenichnikov/.pearrc'. You may probably want to remove it.
Wrote PEAR system config file at: /usr/local/php/etc/pear.conf
You may want to add: /usr/local/php/lib/php to your php.ini include_path
/home/apshenichnikov/php-src/build/shtool install -c ext/phar/phar.phar /usr/local/php/bin
ln -s -f phar.phar /usr/local/php/bin/phar
Installing PDO headers:           /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/pdo/
```

When I run phpinfo I get: "Thread Safety    disabled"
When I try to install pthreads via pecl I get:

```
apshenichnikov@IAS-WS-UX02:~/php-src$ sudo pecl install pthreads
downloading pthreads-3.1.6.tgz ...
Starting to download pthreads-3.1.6.tgz (80,932 bytes)
...................done: 80,932 bytes
28 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootkhkb7n/pthreads-3.1.6
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20151012
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20151012
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.16 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable pthreads... yes, shared
checking whether to enable AddressSanitizer for pthreads... no
checking whether to enable dmalloc for pthreads... no
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

I is sure that that pecl and apache2 uses php recently compiled.
I recomiled PHP using differend branches and make clean.
It is always same result.

Comment: look here, hope it help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758476/6224176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you have built a new copy of PHP, you aren't using it when building the pthreads extension. You can see this in the output from the `./configure` command, where the include files are pointing to your (presumably old) PHP installation:

> checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib

You can fix this by specifying where the config binary is for your fresh build of PHP using the `--with-php-config` setting. According to your installation, it should be located at `/usr/local/php/bin/php-config`